# Efficient way to do Regexp match with a vector of patterns

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to match values in a data.table against a vector containing multiple patterns.  The demo code I have is:

```
library(data.table)

sites <- c("www.google.com", "plus.google.com", "www.yahoo.com", "www.bbc.co.uk")
patterns <- c("bb", "goog")
x <- data.table(sites)

# Regexp version of the in operator, iterates over a group
`%match_in%` <- function (values, match_list) { 
   sapply(values,
       function (x, ml) { 
          any(sapply(ml, grepl, x, ignore.case=TRUE, perl=TRUE))
       } 
       ,match_list
)}

x[sites %match_in% patterns]
```

Which correctly returns:

```
             sites
1:  www.google.com
2: plus.google.com
3:   www.bbc.co.uk
```

However because this contains a nested sapply, it is very slow to run with larger data.tables.

Is there a more efficient way to do this that will work with larger tables?

Comment: NOTE: In the actual code, `patterns` has a few hundred items and the regex includes things like lookbehinds, so putting them in one line wouldn't be practical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're searching for multiple patterns, why not combine the patterns with an `or` syntax? As @Marius suggests, this can be created using `paste0(patterns, collapse = "|")` if you have a lot of patterns to check.

For example,

```
all_patterns = paste0(patterns, collapse = "|")

stringr::str_subset(sites, all_patterns)
[1] "www.google.com"  "plus.google.com" "www.bbc.co.uk"
```

To stick with your `data.table` use-case, perhaps

```
x[stringr::str_detect(sites, all_patterns)]
             sites
1:  www.google.com
2: plus.google.com
3:   www.bbc.co.uk
```

Comment: `paste0(patterns, collapse = "|")` to create the regex when you have large numbers of patterns.

Comment: See my clarification - putting them in one line wouldn't be workable, the paste0 one might though

Comment: It would be good to benchmark whether collapsing the patterns into one large pattern is faster or slower than iterating through a list of patterns.

Comment: str_detect gives me an error:

`i evaluates to a logical vector length 141 but there are 100 rows. `

I've gone with the paste0 approach suggested, with the only change of enclosing each item in brackets to remove confusion due to existing pipes in the patterns.

Timing-wise it's much quicker, 0.014 vs 0.259 using `system.time`

Comment: `cat_patterns <- function(patterns){
  p <- paste0(patterns, collapse = ")|(")
  p <- paste0(p, ")")
  p <- paste0("(", p)
  return(p)
}`

is the function I have used - not sure if there is a more efficient way to write that.

Comment: `str_detect` is vectorised so make sure that your `cat_patterns` is a single pattern-string. Without seeing your regexes I can't really say anything more, but that's another question in any case.